# How to cite reference with Bibtex buy using JabRef when there is Turkish in the citation?

Tags: bibtex, jabref, turkish

As the tittle discribes, I am confused about the using of JabRef when there is Turkish in the authors name - how can I input the names and cite it correctly in Latex?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In addition, there is a special character of "s" in the last author of this paper, which I can't input. The tittle of the paper is: Investments in Renewable and Conventional Energy: The Role of Operational Flexibility

Comment: Welcome. Just replace `\c.S` with `\c{S}`

Answer (score 2):

The complite bibtex file would be

```
@article{kok_20,
  title={Investments in renewable and conventional energy: The role of operational flexibility},
  author={K{\"o}k, A G{\"u}rhan and Shang, Kevin and Y{\"u}cel, {\c{S}}afak},
  journal={Manufacturing \& Service Operations Management},
  volume={22},
  number={5},
  pages={925--941},
  year={2020},
  publisher={INFORMS}
}
```

In case you did not know, Google Scholar has the option to get the BibTex file via cite

[image]

Comment: Awesome, very useful, many thanks!